# working with objects in java, after creating new object cant reach him from main

Tags: java, object

in the main I wrote those two statement:

```
Account newAccount = new Account(name);
newAccount.addNewProduct();
```

this is the constructor code and attribute in Account:

```
private final int MAX_PRODUCTS = 50; //Assumes no more than 50 products per customer
private String name;        //Name of the customer
private int sum;            //Sum amount of the purchase
private Product[] productList;      //List of products for a customer 
private int productCounter;         //Counter for number of products

public Account(String name)
{
    Product[] productList = new Product[MAX_PRODUCTS]; //New empty list of products of the customer }
    productCounter = 0;
    sum = 0;
    name = name;
}
```

I cant figure why, but in this method:

```
public void addNewProduct()
{   
    System.out.println("Name is: " + this.name);
    productList[productCounter] = new Product();
    productCounter++;
}
```

its prints the name as null although i entered a name in the console...
Its like not saving the attributes of the object newAccount I created. why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`name = name` will not work. You need to use `this.name = name`

This is because when you use `name` you refer to the parameter in the constructor; when you use `this.name` you refer to the field.

Comment: ohhh so if I will write in the method decleration :public Account(String newName). and then name = newName. it will be okay?

Answer (score 0):

Just as Anubian Noob Says:

name = name will not work, because you're assingning the same value to the same variable.

If you receive name = "John", what you're doing it's:

John = John.

That's why you need to use this, when you use this.name = name, you're passing the received value to the local variable from your class.

So if you have this:

```
private final int MAX_PRODUCTS = 50; //Assumes no more than 50 products per customer
private String name;        //Name of the customer
private int sum;            //Sum amount of the purchase
private Product[] productList;      //List of products for a customer 
private int productCounter;         //Counter for number of products

public Account(String name)
{
    Product[] productList = new Product[MAX_PRODUCTS];
    productCounter = 0;
    sum = 0;
    this.name = name;
}
```

Your value will be stored on the private variable called name.

Comment: What does this add to the other answer? If you have a suggestion; comment it there, otherwise this is redundant.